# Can I access the failure message from an Assert without a try/catch?

Tags: c#, vs-unit-testing-framework

```
Assert.IsTrue(false, "The assert failed");
```

Is there any way to retrieve this message without using a try catch?

Comment: Why do you need to access the message from within your code? If an Assert fails your unit test should terminate immediately and the results will display your message.

Comment: Outside of viewing it in the Test Explorer window?

Comment: @gunr2171 , I want to create a testing execution report, that's why I need of this message.

Comment: @KennethK. yes.

Comment: If you're creating a testing execution report you want the _results_ of the execution, like a generated xml file which you parse and make into your report. Don't try to extract the results of your test _inside_ your test. Look at the [mstest.exe command line options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), like the `/resultsfile` setting.

Comment: @gunr2171 is there anyway to execute these command line options in the Test Explorer or something similar to them?